# Which one is better for pagination, fetchMore or getServerSideProps?

Tags: pagination, next.js

I want to crate a shopping online website.It have  product pagination fuction.

In the docs of Nextjs, they recommend use getStaticProps and getStaticPaths than other(fetchMore in getStaticProps), but when I search Nextjs pagination, almost docs or tutorial use getServerSideProps or getInitialProps.
i tried to use with fetchMore and i don't see any problem,so why they use getServerSideProps?

My code

```
let paginationOptions: PaginationOptionsInput = {
  skip: 0,
  type: "SALES_DESC",
};

const Index = () => {
  const [filterChecked,setFilterChecked] = useState("SALES_DESC")
  const [currentPage,setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
  const {data,fetchMore,loading} = useGetProductsQuery({
    variables:{
      paginationOptions 
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
  })
  console.log(data?.getProducts.products)
  const handlePageChange = (page:number) =>{
    setCurrentPage(page)
    paginationOptions.skip = 4 * (page-1)
    fetchMore({
      variables:paginationOptions
    })
  }
  

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="distance">
        ...
                    {data?.getProducts.products &&
                      data.getProducts.products!.map((product) => (
                        <div className="col l-3 m-4 c-6" key={product.id}>
                          <div className={styles.productItem}>
                            <img src={product.thumbnail} />
                            <h2>{product.productName}</h2>
                            <h3>{product.priceToDisplay} VND</h3>
                            <div className={styles.paidInfo}>
                              <h4>{product.sales}</h4>
                              <h4>{product.commentAmount}</h4>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      ))}
              <Pagination
        className="pagination-bar"
        currentPage={currentPage}
        totalCount={data?.getProducts.totalCount!}
        pageSize={data?.getProducts.pageSize!}
        onPageChange={(page : number) => handlePageChange(page)}
        />
      ...
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  
  const { data,error,loading } = await client.query<GetProductsQuery>({
    query: GetProductsDocument,
    variables: { paginationOptions },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
  });

  return {
    props: {
      paginationProducts: data.getProducts,
      
    },
  };
};
export default Index;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but:

`getInitialProps` - to forget in nextjs v11+

`getServerSideProps` - every time page is called, [server-side]

`getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` - runs during build, [server-side]

I recommend you to take a look at this [library](https://swr.vercel.app/) [client-side]

When to use `getServerSideProps`(1) vs `getStaticProps` (2)

1. When you have pages where data needs to be loaded every time (example: settings, clients, etc).
2. When you have a lot of pages that need to be rendered, to reach huge performance. (example: product pages, some text pages - for example, "terms and conditions" with data from DB) where you know links previously. It's why in each `getStaticProps` page we need `getStaticPaths`.

SEO optimized pages are `getStaticProps`

So, if you have some rules for the pages, for example `/product/1` `/product/2`  ... `/product/n` you need to create page with `getStaticProps`

Also, take a look at [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration)